# SuiteScript Error when trying to create a new inventory detail subrecord on Work Order Issue

Tags: netsuite

My client side suitescript has following line of code:

```
compSubRec = nlapiCreateCurrentLineItemSubrecord('component', 'componentinventorydetail');
```

For some reason, this results in an error below:

```
INVALID_RCRD_INITIALIZE
You have entered an invalid default value for this record initialize operation.
```

What might this be?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, subrecords are not available in Client Side scripts.  There are only available on Server Side script, e.g. User Event, Scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

As the Document says :

```
nlapiCreateCurrentLineItemSubrecord(sublist, fldname)
```

> This API should only be used in user event scripts on the parent record. Note, however, this API is not supported in beforeLoad user event scripts. This API is also not currently supported in form-level or record-level client SuiteScripts associated with the parent record.

Make sure your script has to be an userevent not a client script.